# Cannot access text file after publishing a window form application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I made an application with C# and it reads text files located on my hard drive but how do I publish the application and include these text files in the final exe so when the application is installed on a different computer it would work and not fail because it cannot locate the text files? I'm using Visual Studio2010

Answer (score 3):

Add the files you want to your solution and then set their Build Action property to Embedded Resource. This will embed the file into your exe. (msdn)

**OR**

Right-click the project file, select Properties.

In the window that opens, go to the Resources tab, and if it has just a blue link in the middle of the tab-page, click it, to create a new resource.

Then from the toolbar above the tab-page, select to add a new text file, give it a name, it will be added to your project and opened up.

If you get this far, then in your code you can type in Resources.TheNameYouGaveTheTextFileHere and you can access its contents. Note that the first time you use the Resources class in a class, you need to add a using directive (hit Ctrl+. after typing Resources to get the menu to get VS to do it for you).

Answer (score -1):

Check  [Step-by-Step](http://balanagaraj.wordpress.com/2007/05/29/create-exe-or-setup-file-in-net-windows-application/)  Process for the same.

Please Google Before asking any question on stack